# iPad fullscreen mode: Open a URL **as if it were a link**

Tags: javascript, ios, html, ipad, mobile-safari

I want to do the **opposite** of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7390672/340947).

Basically I have the URL in a JS string and I want to navigate to it but I want it to open it in the Safari app, so I can switch back to the fullscreen app to continue on the original page.

By using `window.open` or setting `location.href` or anything like that will make it impossible to return since there is no back button in the fullscreen mode.

I tried to make a dummy `<a>` tag with the `href` set to the url, but I found there's no way to trigger a click on it with jQuery.

Comment: Awesome! Someone used subjunctive when they were supposed to. :)

Answer (score 0):

Triggering a click using `Document.createEvent('MouseEvents')` and then init'ing it with 'initMouseEvent' works to emulate clicks.