# How to open Safari from a WebApp in iOS 7

Tags: javascript, ios, web-applications, safari, mobile-safari

In previous versions of iOS, `<a>` tags would open Mobile Safari, and you had to intercept those to instead stay inside the webapp (an HTML page that has been saved to the home screen by the user).

Starting in iOS 7, all links are staying inside the WebApp. I cannot figure out how to get it to open Safari, when I really want it to.

I've tried using `window.open` and `a target="_blank"` but neither works.

Here is a sample. https://s3.amazonaws.com/kaontest/testopen/index.html

If you save that to your home screen in iOS 6, the link opens Safari. But in iOS 7, it doesn't.

Note that this is the OPPOSITE question that everyone is usually asking ("how to NOT open Safari"). That behavior seems to be the new default, and I can't figure out how to get the old behavior back!

Comment: FYI: Someone over on the apple dev lists said they think this is a bug. So perhaps what I'm looking for is a clever work-around until Apple fixes it?

Comment: It is a bug indeed. Although they might decide to mark it as "Won't Fix". Can you just follow the link? Removing that "_blank" should work.

Comment: The page I'm going to is something the user is going to want to email, bookmark or print, so staying inside my web app is problematic. They really need all the browser doohickeys.

Comment: I have confirmed that this is fixed in 7.0.3

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Having an anchor tag with target `_blank`will work in iOS 7.0.3 but using window.open will not work and will remain to open within the webview in 7.0.3:

```
window.open('http://www.google.com/', '_blank');
```

Comment: This does not work for me with iOS 7.0.6. Only [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21048408/1821792) worked for me.

Answer (score 25):

**Update 10/23/13: Fixed in iOS 7.0.3. Add a target="xxx" attribute to your links to do this. Also works with mailto: and friends.**

**This is a bug in iOS 7.0, 7.0.1 and 7.0.2 and there's no known way to do this.**

It's a regression from earlier versions of iOS, where links that open in Safari work just fine. It appears to be a part of a cluster of problems revolving around opening URLs, with no external URL schemes working (for example "mailto:" doesn't work either).

The usual suspects of working around a problem like this unfortunately don't work (for example using a form and submitting it with a target of "_new").

There's other grave issues, like alert and confirm modal dialogs not working at all.

It *may* help to submit these as bugs to Apple, http://bugreport.apple.com

Comment: Is there an active bug report we can watch the progress on?

Comment: @scunliffe Apple's bug reports are unfortunately not public. I've submitted a few reports about this problem and some others and will definitely report about any progress being made, Apple's NDAs permitting.

Comment: I'd just like to add, for googlers, that `itms-services` urls for installing enterprise applications via web apps are broken too.

Comment: Just wanted to let any one following this know that iOS 7.0.3 seems to fix the issue. I've keep standalone webapps saved for testing and the update released today restored external link/app functionality.

Comment: I have confirmed that this is fixed in 7.0.3

Answer (score 6):

This is a known issue for the last couple months of betas. There are no work arounds, and from what I can tell Apple has been silent on any ETAs on fixes, or even recognizing it's a bug. Bug reports have been submitted, but not updated/responded to.

More: http://www.mobilexweb.com/blog/safari-ios7-html5-problems-apis-review

Answer (score 1):

I found two solutions for the time being to this problem, both of which obviously using `preventDefault` on the external links.

If you're linking to another website or something to download, the only option I see is to ironically alert the user to hold their finger on the link to get the touch callout prompt. Then again, depending if it's a website or a PDF, instruct them to either copy the link or in the case of a PDF, add it to their reading list. Since the alert and confirm modals are also broken you'll need to implement your own modal notifications. If you already have that it shouldn't be that much trouble.

**Update** [2013-10-25] Apparently it's been fixed in iOS 7.0.3 and links open in Safari...

**Edit** [2013-10-05] Here's pretty much what I use with a jQuery UI modal

```
// iOS 7 external link polyfill
$('a[rel=external], a[rel=blank], a[target=_blank], a[href$=".pdf"]').on('click', function(e) {

  if (navigator.standalone && /iP(hone|od|ad) OS 7/.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
    e.preventDefault(); e.stopPropagation();

    var href = $(this).attr('href');

    var $dialog = $('<div id="ios-copy"></div>')
      .html('<p>iOS 7 prevents us from opening external links in Safari, you can continue to the address and risk losing all navigation or you can copy the address to your clipboard by <strong>holding your finger on the link</strong> for a few seconds.</p><p><a style="background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.75); color: #fff; font-size: 1.25em; padding: 1em;" href="' + href + '">' + href + '</a></p>')
      .appendTo('body')
      .dialog({
        title: 'External link',
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
          Ok: function() {
            $( this ).dialog( "close" );
          }
        }
      });
  }
});
```

The other workaround is using ajax or an iframe to load the external content, but unless you have a good sub-browser or something in your app it will look sketchy. Here's something along those lines.

```
// iOS 7 external link polyfill
if (/iP(hone|od|ad) OS 7/.test(navigator.userAgent) && window.navigator.standalone) {
  $('a[rel=external], a[href$=".pdf"]').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); e.stopPropagation();

    var link = this;
    var href = $(link).attr('href');

    var frameContainer = $('<div></div>').css({
      position: 'absolute',
      left: 10,
      top: $(link).position().top,
      opacity: 0,
      overflow: 'scroll',
      '-webkit-overflow-scrolling': 'touch',
      height: 520,
      transition: 'opacity .25s',
      width: 300
    });

    var iosFrame = $('<iframe class="iosFrame" seamless="seamless" width="1024" height="5000"></iframe>')
      .attr('src', href)
      .css({
        height: 5000,
        'max-width': 1024,
        width: 1024,
        overflow: 'scroll !important',
        '-webkit-overflow-scrolling': 'touch !important'
      });

    var iosFrameClose = $('<a href="#"><i class="icon-cancel icon-remove icon-3x"></i></a>').css({
      position: 'absolute',
      left: -10,
      top: $(link).position().top - 20,
      'text-shadow': '1px 1px 1px #000',
      transition: 'opacity .25s',
      opacity: 0,
      '-webkit-transform': 'translate3d(0, 0, 0)',
      width: '3em',
      height: '3em'
    }).on('click', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      setTimeout( function() {
        $(frameContainer).remove();
        $(iosFrameClose).remove();
      }, 250);
    });

    iosFrame.appendTo(frameContainer);
    frameContainer.appendTo('body');
    iosFrameClose.appendTo('body');

    iosFrame.contents().css({
      '-webkit-transform': 'translate3d(0, 0, 0)'
    });

    // Show this thing
    setTimeout( function() {
      $(frameContainer).css({ opacity: 1 });
      $(iosFrameClose).css({ opacity: 1 });
    }, 1);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE
Just wanted to let any one following this know that iOS 7.0.3 seems to fix the issue. I've keep standalone webapps saved for testing and the update released today restored external link/app functionality. So I've updated my code to let customers know to update their phones instead of deleting and re saving the web app.

---

I was going to just add a comment but apparently this is too long.

Apple set the stage for a WebApp world when they allowed chromeless webapps to be saved to the homescreen of the device. This "bug" feels like a major step backwards. It doesn't seem very apple to leave such a gapping bug in a final release. At least not one that, once they become aware of it, they don't publicly state they are working on a fix for it like they did with the lockscreen bypasses. I can't help that this feels intentional though there doesn't seem to be a clear reason why.

For developers dealing with this issue the only solution I could find was to

1st) Set the meta tag apple-mobile-web-app-capable to "no" - this prevents future users from dealing with the problem

2nd) Updated the code in our webapp to look for "standalone" and iOS version 7+. When conditions are meet I offered a popup that stated the issue and added a link to that page and asked the users for their forgivness and requested they copy the link and paste in in safari.

I wrapped the link in edge to edge  tag with line breaks above and bellow to help make the copy and pasting process of the url a bit easier.

Answer (score 1):

iOS v7.0.3 released 10/22/13 fixes the problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
window.open('http://www.google.com/'); // stays in web app view

<a href='http://www.google.com/' target='_blank'>Click Here</a> // opens in safari
```

If you want to open Safari, but using an anchor tag like this isn't possible for whatever reason, [the JavaScript solution to this question will open in Safari as well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7930001/force-link-to-open-in-mobile-safari-from-a-web-app-with-javascript#answer-8833025).

Comment: I can confirm that the second option works on iOS 7.0.6

Answer (score -1):

It looks suspiciously like an intentional bug to limit the ability of web apps to deliver advertisements. Maybe you can try open the new page in an iframe.

Answer (score -1):

EDIT: Sorry, I misread your original problem. This solution was for opening an external website at all. Basic A href tags used to work in opening links and stopped working in iOS7. This was the only way I could get it to open an external link at all.

---

Here's how I got it to sort of work with a webapp saved to desktop in iOS7.

```
function openpage()
{
window.open('http://www.yourlinkhere.com', '_blank');
}
```

...

```
<a ontouchstart="openpage();" onclick="openpage();">LINKED TEXT</a>
```

The issue though is that it seems to ignore the target option and it opens it in the same full screen desktop webapp and there is no way to navigate back that I can see.

Comment: This does not solve my problem, since my problem is exactly what you listed as "The issue though…"

Answer (score -1):

```
window.open('http://www.google.com/', '_system');
```

this will open native Safari Application even on latest version of iOS...

Happy coding!!

Comment: That doesn't work in the current iOS. It opens the link locally, just like _blank. I can't find any documentation of the target "_system" except in Cordova, so I'm guessing that's an extension they added. We are talking about "save to home screen" web apps here, not apps in phonegap-like wrappers.

Answer (score -2):

Maybe you should remove the meta setting of "apple-mobile-web-app-capable" in the head of page2.html

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/ConfiguringWebApplications/ConfiguringWebApplications.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002051-CH3-SW1

Comment: This would remove web-app mode for new users, but users with it already installed would still encounter the problems.