# iOS: Excluding certain URLs when running webview

Tags: html, ios, swift, webview, uiwebview

I am using Swift and have web-based content (an external webpage) embedded in WebView for my native app. On that webpage, again, which is in-app, I need to make one link open in Safari and not in the App. HTML target _blank code on the webpage doesn’t work (I wish it was that easy), looking for the right code to do it in Swift.

I have used this code for uiwebview:

```
@IBOutlet var news: UIWebView!
   var theURL = "http://"

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    loadWebPage()

}
func loadWebPage(){
    let requestURL = NSURL (string: theURL)
    let URLrequest = NSURLRequest (URL: requestURL!)
    news.loadRequest(URLrequest)
```

I have used this code for WKNaviagtionDelegate:

```
func webView(webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyForNavigationAction navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: ((WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void)) {
    if (navigationAction.navigationType == WKNavigationType.LinkActivated && !navigationAction.request.URL!.host!.lowercaseString.hasPrefix("http://")) {
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(navigationAction.request.URL!)
        decisionHandler(WKNavigationActionPolicy.Cancel)
    } else {
       decisionHandler(WKNavigationActionPolicy.Allow)
    }
```

Best, Drew

Comment: Could you show us what you've tried already (relevant code snippets, etc.)?

Comment: I just updated my post with the two forms of code I used.

Answer (score 0):

Because you need to create a button that looks like a link.

that should do the trick:

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: "http://...")!)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, but I am already aware of that code. I got rejected by apple for not being user friendly enough. I am looking for a code which will cause the user to exit the uiwebview when they enter a certain url.

Comment: What version of IOS you want your app running?

Comment: I have my iOS version set for 7.0 and later and I am running xcode 6.4.

Comment: Can you check the policy off apple.
Like 
12.3
Apps that are simply web clippings, content aggregators, or a collection of links, may be rejected

[link]https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#functionality

Comment: Thanks for bringing this to my attention, but I have other parts of the app including emergency numbers, maps, and games. I am trying to make a part where students can easily navigate and understand the website.

Answer (score 0):

If the button is actually on a webpage in WebView... the link is not really controlled by the App unless you manipulate the link in iOS. It looks like the HTML target="_new" tag on the button might work in a later version of iOS. It's a bug in iOS 7 and was fixed in 7.0.3. Try a higher iOS version target for the App with the HTML target tag on the button.
[How to open Safari from a WebApp in iOS 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18879631/how-to-open-safari-from-a-webapp-in-ios-7)