# html5 video in a webapp on iPad plays only the first time I load the page. How can I solve?

Tags: html, ipad, video, web-applications

I have a webapp written in HTML5.
The Home page contains a `<video>` tag.
The video is correctly played when I load the page for the first time, and if I use controls (pause, play, fullscreen) too.
In order to maintain the webapp always in the fullscreen view, I used only one html page, and when a button (or an anchor) is clicked, I hide the container div (representing the content of the logical "home page"), and show the selected one, when the "home" button is played I show again the original container div.
Originally, the video continued playing when I clicked a button to pass to another virtual page, so I pause it by jquery.
The problem is: only on **iPad**, when I come back to the first container (that means the home page), the video is no more available, I can't see the poster and the video itself, and the div is black screen.

Some notes I hope could restrict the problem:

1. The video is statically loaded in a `<video>` tag and source
   attribute.
2. I've tried to start with an empty src and load it by
       jQuery (as explained in many tutorials and in stackoverflow too), it's the same.
3. The same if I try to create a playlist in
       which I select different videos and load the selected one in the
       `<video>` tag using Javascript.
4. I also tried to reload the page with jQuery, but doesn't work.

The constant beahviours are the following:

- Every technique I tried to implement is working well on PC with
  Firefox and on the Mac with Safari.
- The problem on the iPad appears only when I try to come back to the initial page.

I'm not convinced the problem depends on the technique of show/hide I used, but on the iPad behaviour. I've read some other ways to maintain the webapp in fullscreen view, but apply only to `<a>` tags (such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6429492/how-do-you-keep-an-iphone-ipad-web-app-in-full-screen-mode/7841521#7841521):), I need div stylized as buttons (and managed in jQuery) too.

Thanks if someone can help

Answer (score 0):

I think if you use flowplayer is better it is good implementaton that it work on IPhone and Andriod, it is free.

Comment: I need the webapp works on iPad (from ios6 to ios8), flowplayer provides this? I would like to understand, however, if I'm doing anything wrong or iit's a known problem, too.

Comment: http://flash.flowplayer.org/plugins/javascript/ipad.html this link describe how to run the flowplayer on iphone, and ipad good luck I do it for one of sites i work on before