# iPad add to homepage stops site from working

Tags: iphone, html, ios, ipad

I'm using the IOS simulator iPad/ ISO 4.3.2 (8H7)

I'm working on a web based app for the iPad, it works fine being viewed as a webpage on my local host.

However, when I click add to homepage button and access the site via the icon on the homepage.

All the 'a' tags stop working.

EDIT: I've found another post that people mention the same issue. See the second and third posts down.

[iPad WebApp Full Screen in Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3024434/ipad-webapp-full-screen-in-safari)

Comment: What do you mean by "all tags stop working" and did you test it on an actual device?

Comment: Do you have any code u would like to show?

Comment: agreed, what do you mean by tags? Do you mean tabs?

Comment: Apologizes I wrote <a> but didn't realize it wasn't showing.

Comment: @WTP I don't have an iPad but I'm using the simulator that came with the latest SDK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I have been able to get this to work is by changing all my 'a' tags to the following.

```
a href="javascript:this.location = 'page.php'"
```

For some reason when you link with javascript it stays in the same window.

Comment: More semantic way would be: <a href="page.php" onclick="location=this.href;return false;">...