# Change iPad/iPhone layout if user adds to homepage

Tags: iphone, html, css, ipad, iphone-standalone-web-app

In iPhone/iPad you can have the address bar removed by using a meta-tag on your page. However it only works if a user clicks the 'add to home page button'.

For more info [iPad WebApp Full Screen in Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3024434/ipad-webapp-full-screen-in-safari)

I need to find a way to slightly change the CSS if the user is viewing the page without the address bar(i.e. accessing the site from homepage.).

```
padding-top:64px;
```

Has anyone found a way to deal with this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should look at `window.navigator.standalone` in JS and then, for example, set `standalone` class to `HTML` element, so you could add the following rule to your CSS that would be applied only when the page is added to homepage:

```
.standalone .yourElement {
    padding-top: 64px;
}
```